# Bootstrap labels acting weird when echoing them with PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having a few issues with PHP and Bootstrap labels.

This is my code:

```
<?php
  $fp = fsockopen("123.456.78.9", 80, $errno, $errstr, 0.4); //(line 2)
?>

<li><strong>Server Status:</strong> //(line 85)
                <?
                if (!$fp) {
                  echo '<span class="label label-danger">Offline</span>';
                }else{
                  echo '<span class="label label-success">Online</span>';}
                ?>
                <br>
</li>
```

And this is what it is doing that it shouldn't be doing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRwIs.png

It's needless to say what is wrong here. I know that the online checker is working, I just don't know why it is echoing part of the PHP code.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This happens when you nest double quotes inside single quotes. You should escape them with \ character.

Comment: Hi, you should hide that ip address in this post. People might access it.

Comment: Yeah... hiding the ip would be a good idea... but now I know that there's a metro bootstrap version :D

Comment: Please don't use the shorthand `<?` instead of `<?php`.  It's not a good idea for code that may need to be moved to different servers (some do not support the shorthand `<?` for PHP, it has to be enabled.

Comment: I always forget about escaping quotes. If I had knew this before  it would solve pretty much every problem I have ever had in PHP. Thanks so much !

Comment: @Ertunç Actually, there's nothing wrong with nesting double quotes inside single quotes. The only quotes you need to escape are single quotes inside single quotes, or double quotes inside double quotes. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Well I changed it to echo "<span class=\"label label-success\">Online</span>"; and that is working fine. Thanks for your help! Also, I changed the <? tag to <?php. The servers this will be ran on are all self-managed, but I supose it's betetr to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $fp = fsockopen("188.165.215.30", 80, $errno, $errstr, 0.4); //(line 2)
 ?>

 <li><strong>Server Status:</strong> //(line 85)
            <?php //you missed php tag here
            if (!$fp) {
              echo '<span class="label label-danger">Offline</span>';
            }else{
              echo '<span class="label label-success">Online</span>';}
            ?>
            <br>
 </li>
```

Comment: You should also include a summary of any fixes you do make so the question creator understands the problem and how to solve it for next time.

Comment: @Axel didn't I do?You are welcome to suggest what else I have to describe.

Comment: Sorry, your comment is kind of obscured by the code itself.  I'd recommend including a note outside of the code so it's more clear.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:you forgot to add php tag.

```
<?php
    if (!$fp) {
    echo '<span class="label label-danger">Offline</span>';
    }else{
    echo '<span class="label label-success">Online</span>';}
?>
```

Comment: @JamesS1 try my above code and let me know if it works for you :)